# when a sql server agent job is created and scheduled should we start running the job manually for the first time or will it start automatically

Tags: sql-server, sql-agent-job

I have created a Sql Server agent job and scheduled it to run every 10 mins. 
For the first time, when it runs should we need to run the job manually once before it starts with scheduled time. Basically how does the job run for the first time.

Also when the job is created the owner of the job is in disabled state. will this effect the schedule of the job?

Answer (score 2):

The job will run on the schedule you provide - there is no need to run it manually to "prime" the schedule.

Disabled jobs are never executed by schedule - the scheduled executions will be skipped. They can still be executed manually.

If you have a disabled job which you wish to be triggered by a schedule, you must enable it first.